# ASP .NET MVC 6 Without DNX

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to install MVC 6 beta in a regular .NET 4.5.2 web project (not DNX). It gives me an error. Is this possible? Or will it eventually be supported?

```
PM> install-package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -pre
Attempting to gather dependencies information for package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.6.0.0-beta5' with respect to project '6 - Entry Points\Sample.Web', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1'
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.6.0.0-beta5' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving actions to install package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.6.0.0-beta5'
Resolved actions to install package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.6.0.0-beta5'
Install failed. Rolling back...
Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 6.0.0-beta5' does not exist in project 'Sample.Web'
Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 6.0.0-beta5' does not exist in folder 'C:\Dev\Sample\packages'
Install-Package : Could not install package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 6.0.0-beta5'. You are trying to install this 
package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1', but the package does not contain any assembly 
references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package 
author.At line:1 char:1
+ install-package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -pre
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackage 
   Command
```

Comment: i believe that mvc6 depends on .net 4.6

Comment: mvc6 needs dnx type project

Comment: So you'll never be able to run MVC 6 on IIS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't. And no, it won't be eventually supported.

Comment: Not being able to use MVC 6 in a non-DNX application doesn't mean that IIS doesn't support MVC 6: IIS has a specific DNX loader that is part of the `AspNet.Loader` DLL added to the `wwwroot` folder. It's not public yet, but nothing prevents you from using ILSpy if you want to know how it works internally.

Comment: What is the dependency? In server.ini it looks like it's using a regular http listener just like an owin self hosted web app